# How to return when inserting into multiple tables as part of a views on inert rule

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create rules for my views so that I don't have to insert into multiple tables at once but I need to return the new row and I cannot work how to return from multiple insert statements.

This rule works fine but obviously returns nothing:

```
create rule template_field_insert as on insert to template_field 
do instead (
    insert into public.base (
        id,
        organisation_id,
        last_modified_by,
        armicus_data
    )
    values (
        new.id,
        new.organisation_id,
        new.last_modified_by,
        new.armicus_data
    )
    insert into public.template_field_data (
        id,
        template_id,
        format_id,
        armicus_name,
        description,
        armicus_configuration,
        required
    )
    values (
        new.id,
        new.template_id,
        new.format_id,
        new.armicus_name,
        new.description,
        new.armicus_configuration,
        new.required
    )
)
```

I tried this but it just throws a syntax error on the first insert:

```
create rule template_field_insert as on insert to template_field 
do instead (
    (
        insert into public.base (
            id,
            organisation_id,
            last_modified_by,
            armicus_data
        )
        values (
            new.id,
            new.organisation_id,
            new.last_modified_by,
            new.armicus_data
        )
        returning *
    ) b, (
        insert into public.template_field_data (
            id,
            template_id,
            format_id,
            armicus_name,
            description,
            armicus_configuration,
            required
        )
        values (
            new.id,
            new.template_id,
            new.format_id,
            new.armicus_name,
            new.description,
            new.armicus_configuration,
            new.required
        )
        returning *
    ) f
    select b.id, f.armicus_name
    from b
    join f on b.id = f.id
)
```

I have achieved this with CTEs outside of the view but you cannot use NEW inside a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link for a working answer using triggers instead of rules: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239690/how-to-return-when-inserting-into-multiple-tables-as-part-of-a-views-on-inert-ru/239692#239692